# Submatrix of a sparse matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm writing a C++ matrix library (https://github.com/frozenca/Ndim-Matrix). I'm planning for supporting sparse matrices.
What gives me a big headache is to implement submatrix operation.

For example, I expect something like this:

```
// (5 0 6 0)
// (0 1 0 2)
// (3 0 4 0)
// (0 7 0 8)
SparseMat<int> m1 {{5,0,6,0},{0,1,0,2},{3,0,4,0},{0,7,0,8}};

// (1 0)
// (0 4)
auto m2 = m1.submatrix({1,1},{3,3}); // non-owning view for m1's internal buffer

m2 *= 2;

// now m is
// (5 0 6 0)
// (0 2 0 2)
// (3 0 8 0)
// (0 7 0 8)

// (1 0)
// (0 2)
// (3 0)
SparseMat<int> m3 {{1, 0}, {0, 2}, {3, 0}};

// (2 0)
// (0 16)
// (6 0)
auto m4 = matmul(m3, m2); // shouldn't copy m1.
```

For dense matrices, my library implements submatrix as non-owning view with the pointer to the buffer and local strides. The code above works correctly for dense matrices. For sparse matrices, how can I emulate this with high performance (i.e. no element copy)?

Comment: Just of the top of my head, a reference to the original (sparse) matrix, the `x` and `y` coordinates of the submatrix, and the width and height of the submatrix? Then let it be a thin proxy to the real underlying (sparse) matrix for all element access?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, for dense matrices my code exactly behaves as you described. (actually, it doesn't have a reference to matrix, it has a pointer to the buffer of the original matrix) for sparse matrices, it's giving me headache to select appropriate data structure and algorithm

Comment: Then you don't really have to do anything specific for views to sparse matrixes. Let the original sparse matrix handle things like validation and bounds-checking and (most importantly) figure out if the requested element exists or not.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. What have you tried?

Comment: @Evg I've tried element index set approach (for above example, ```m2``` contains ```{2, 5}``` as a proxy of list of element indices of ```m1```). I'm looking for a better approach, the matrix multiplication benchmark was not satisfactory

Comment: What is a submatrix exactly? Is it a *contiguous* region inside the original matrix?

Comment: I suggest that you include this information into the question. If you're looking for performance, sparse matrix storage format should also be specified.

Comment: And how do you represent a sparse matrix?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I'm using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format) and CSC format, for row/column majors respectively

Comment: If your goal is efficient matrix multiplication, then the question should not be how to represent the submatrix, but how to *iterate* over its rows or columns. Your unit of work in not an element, but an entire row (or column). I would probably have something like `rowIterator.getNextNonzeroElement()` to return the element and its index. Now the matrix iterator and the submatrix iterator for row-major matrices are one and the same thing, only `begin()` and `end()` are different. Naturally the other operand of multiplication should be column-major, and `columnIterator` should be efficient.